# Angular ng-class depending on image aspect

Tags: angularjs, image, conditional-statements, aspect-ratio, ng-class

How can I set a ng-class (inside ng-repeat) depending on image aspect ratio?

something like...

```
<div ng-repeat="img in images" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
   <img ng-src="{{img}}" ng-class="{'wide': img.width/img.height > 1, 'tall': img.width/img.height <= 1}" />
</div>
```

EDIT: CSS object-fit doesn't work for me because of IE... :(

Comment: That looks like it should work. Is it not working for you?

Comment: Nop... "img.width" is not a property of img array....  I'd like to get the image width and height but I don't know how

Comment: Oh, ha...gotcha. Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14508318/548997) help? Sounds like you will need to write a directive (which is pretty standard any time you start wanting to mess with the DOM).

Comment: Hey Lex, thanks for your fast answer... Maybe yes, but I get lost here... 
`//check width and height and apply styling to parent here`.

I'm new on this, I appreciate your help!

Comment: I also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1892815/5904036) but ... doesn't work with my images... maybe because of ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many times serching for it, I found a simple and sexy answer...  It is a CSS img element property called object-fit. It could have these values: fill, contain, cover, scale, none.

```css
img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is waiting for the image to load before setting the width / height properties on the img json object.  So something like this will work.

Important: Scope.apply - Because you are altering the scope in a non-angular context, i.e. in jQuery you need to call scope.apply so the digest-watch cycle occurs and the variables get set up correctly.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JmsDxJ?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{img}}" image-set-aspect ng-class="{'wide':    img.width/img.height > 1, 'tall': img.width/img.height <= 1}" />
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('imageSetAspect', function() {
    return {
        scope: false,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('load', function() {
            // Use jquery on 'element' to grab image and get dimensions.
            scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.imageMeta.width = $(element).width(); 
              scope.imageMeta.height = $(element).height(); 
              console.log(scope.$parent.imageMeta);
            });
        });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU Dr Jones.  Really I don't need the properties, it was just a "sketch".  The important thing here is apply 'wide' or 'tall' classes correctly.

[This](https://plnkr.co/edit/nXzDbM5GldH8jezLXZA5?p=preview) is the plunker. You'll see an example of expected result. Thanks again for your help and your time!

Comment: Updated solution above.

Comment: Dr Jones, thank you, the plunker is already!   But in my application is not working... something wrong with this two lines `scope.$parent.imagen.width = $(element).width();` and `scope.$parent.imagen.height = $(element).height();`

In debug mode, I'm not seeing pass the values `$(element).width();` to `scope.$parent.imageMeta.width`... after this line, `scope.$parent.imageMeta.width`is undefined.

Comment: ...And what would be a solution in the angular context?

Comment: I updated the code to remove $parent.  Not really needed.  Since this works in Plunker I think the question is answered.  I think it's up to you to take it from here.